# How to figure out what exact entity resulted in DbContext.SaveChanges FK conflict failure

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

With Entity Framework Core (in case it matters, I'm using version 2.2), I update a number of entities in the DB context and call `SaveChanges`. In case saving fails because of the foreign key issue, I can't figure out what exact entities have foreign key issues. Is it possible to figure this out?

When Foreign Key conflict happens, `SQL Server` returns an error with code 547 and text `The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "<Constraint>". The conflict occurred in database "<Database name>", table "<Table name>", column '<Column name>'` without reference to exact invalid rows.

I have looked at `DbUpdateException` properties, but no luck:

```
var dbUpdateEx = ex as DbUpdateException;
var erroredEntries = dbUpdateEx.Entries; 
// The documentation says that Entries property "Gets the entries that were involved in the error", 
// but in my case it's always empty.
```

Also, I have tried validating entities manually before save, but such validation does not find FK conflicts. Code sample:

```
var valProvider = new ValidationDbContextServiceProvider(dbContext);
var valContext = new ValidationContext(entity, valProvider, null);
var entityErrors = new List<ValidationResult>();
var result = Validator.TryValidateObject(entity, valContext, entityErrors, true);
```

When I save more than 100 records and the save fails because of FK conflict in a single entity, it's quite frustrating to look for this single invalid record by hand.

Comment: Do you have batch updates enabled? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating  That might prevent entity-by-entity error tracking.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, In SQL Server Profiler I see separate 'exec sp_executesql' for each row, so I guess there is no batching.